# R: Plot and Save rasterbrick layers separately with common legend scale

Tags: r, plot, raster, r-raster

I have a multiband rasterbrick object and I am looking for an efficient solution to plot and save each of those separately in .jpg format. 
I cannot use spplot() or levelplot() because the object has 100 layers.

Currently I plan to write each of the layers as separate .tiff and use Arcgis to plot. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/06yq26ohmcyp97b/old_gap_.tif?dl=0) is the layer I am working on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write a function to save JPEG plots then use `sapply`

```
library(raster)

rand_raster <- function() {
  r <- raster(nrows = 10, ncols = 10)
  r[] <- runif(100)
  r
}

s <- brick(rand_raster(), rand_raster(), rand_raster())
breaks <- seq(from = min(summary(s)["Min.", ]),
              to = max(summary(s)["Max.", ]),
              length.out = 5)
palette <- colorRampPalette(colors = c("blue", "red"))
cols <- palette(5)

raster_plot <- function(x, s) {
  jpeg(filename = paste(names(s[[x]]), ".jpg"))
  plot(s[[x]], breaks = breaks, col = cols)
  dev.off()
}

sapply(1:nlayers(s), function(x) raster_plot(x, s))
```

Comment: Thank you! sboysel. This helps but the legend for all the rasters plotted are not same. The legend scale differs as per max and  min value of the individual data-layers.

Comment: Try using the `scalebar` function after the call to `plot`.  You should be able to fix a scale.

Comment: sboysel, the scalebar works for the distance scale. Here I was referring to the raster data legend.

Comment: I see.  See my edited answer.  The `breaks` argument in `plot` fixes the scale to a global min and max.  You can modify the number of breaks and colors to your liking.